# Setting Range object Value

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to set the value of a cell of a range passed to the function and it always throws an exception when setting the cell value, even though I traced it to know that the code can read the cell value.  Below function contains code in the Case "XS" that always creates an exception.  Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

This function builds and sets an output table in the same sheet with an accumulation of man-days of effort and % complete values.

Input:

```
IssueTable:  2D array of search data
Term1:       0 if searching for 0%, 1 if 100%, -1 if started (between 0 and 1)
Term1_Col:   Column in IssueTabel containing %Done (leftmost is 1)
Filter:      Filter term
Filter_Col:  Column containing Filter
Size_Col:    Column containing Filter
Effort_Col:  Column containing level of Effort (LOE) data
Done_Col:    Column containing %Done data
OutputTable: 2D array of output data
```

Output:

OutputTable:
   Range filled with data in the form:

```
Size   LOE     %Done
XS     dd      %%
S      dd      %%
M      dd      %%
L      dd      %%
XL     dd      %%
```

code:

```
Public Function Build_SizeDistribution(IssueTable As Range, Term1 As 
 Integer, Term1_Col As Integer, Filter As String, Filter_Col As Integer, 
 Size_Col As Integer, Effort_Col As Integer, Done_Col As Integer, 
 OutputTable As Range)

Dim i As Integer
Dim state As String
Dim LOE As Variant
Dim retval As String
Dim dest As Range
Dim src As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
ws.Activate

With ws

Set src = .Range(IssueTable.Address)
Set dest = .Range(OutputTable.Address)

For i = 1 To src.Rows.Count
    If src.Cells(i, Term1_Col).Value = Term1 Or ((Term1 < 0) And (src.Cells(i, Term1_Col).Value > 0) And (src.Cells(i, Term1_Col).Value < 1)) Then
        If src.Cells(i, Filter_Col).Value = Filter Then
            state = src.Cells(i, Size_Col).Value
            LOE = src.Cells(i, Effort_Col).Value

            Select Case state
                Case "XS"
                     Set rng = dest.Item(1, 2)
                     rng.Value = rng.Value + LOE
                     LOE = 3   ' just to have something for the debugger to stop on
                Case "S"
                     Set rng = dest.Cells(2, 2)
                     rng.Value = rng.Value + LOE
                Case "M"
                     Set rng = dest.Cells(3, 2)
                     rng.Value = rng.Value + LOE
                Case "L"
                     Set rng = dest.Cells(4, 2)
                     rng.Value = rng.Value + LOE
                Case "XL"
                     Set rng = dest.Cells(5, 2)
                     rng.Value = rng.Value + LOE
                End Select
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With
Build_SizeDistribution = retval
End Function
```

Comment: What is the value of `LOE` when the error occurs? And what is the error message?

Comment: Can you update the question to show the statement you are using to call the function as well - there may be something in your parameters that isn't valid.

Comment: You aren't trying to use this as a UDF are you?

Comment: LOE at the point of error is correct and comes from the InputTable.  It is typically a float, so I set the LOE as a variant.  Typical call cell function is:   =Build_SizeDistribution(A11:Q141,1,2,"Initial",4,14,3,2,G151:I155)  I have traced the rng variable at is it good (I used to have a line that set a string variable to the .Address and it is within the OutputTable range of cells.  I can read cell data all day long, but not set the value of a cell.

Comment: I tried not using .value, using Set, not using Set, playing with the Select, etc.  No combination of things I have tried works.  I always get a #VALUE! error as a function return (?).

Comment: Sorry, YowE3K, I don't know what a UDF means in this context.